# change root path in Laravel

Tags: angular, laravel

A have two seperate Laravel project and Angular project. I build Angular project in the Laravel project by changing the angular.json output path to ..Laravel-Project/public/app and build the project using,
ng build --base-href localhost:8000/app command.

After building, it builds in the path Laravel-Project/public/app but, to run it, I have to change the index.html from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/runtime.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="/app/polyfills.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="/app/styles.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="/app/vendor.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="/app/main.js"></script>
```

at every time I build the project. It always search javascript files in the public folder instead the app folder. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some researches I found that It can only be done with Laravel views. So I can store the updated index.html in another folder and make a route redirection from build path to new folder path.
Otherwise I have to do it manually.